# CompilationTarget to C takes long compilation time

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

Consider I have a function, with one version that compiled to the virtual machine and one that compiled to C:

```
fcp1[C0_, {xmin_, xmax_}, {tmin_, tmax_, dt_}] :=
 Compile[{},
  Module[{xls, Nx, tls, Ct, cdiagT, cdiagh, dx},
   Nx = Length[C0];
   dx = N@(xmax - xmin)/(Nx - 1);
   tls = Range[tmin, tmax, dt] + dt/2.;
   cdiagT = -1./(2. dx^2);
   Do[
    cdiagh = cdiagT;
    , {t, tls}]]
  , CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
    "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
  ]


fcp2[C0_, {xmin_, xmax_}, {tmin_, tmax_, dt_}] :=
 Compile[{},
  Module[{xls, Nx, tls, Ct, cdiagT, cdiagh, dx},
   Nx = Length[C0];
   dx = N@(xmax - xmin)/(Nx - 1);
   tls = Range[tmin, tmax, dt] + dt/2.;
   cdiagT = -1./(2. dx^2);
   Do[
    cdiagh = cdiagT;
    , {t, tls}]]
  , CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
    "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]
```

Now if we compare their compilation speed (the time it take MMA to compile the function, not the time to execute the function), the C compilation is very slow:

```
Nxgrid = 2000;

Ct0 = Array[Exp[-5. #^2] &, Nxgrid, {-1., 1.}] // 
   Developer`ToPackedArray;

xRange = {-199.9`, 199.9`};

dt = 0.05515999116515042`;

Ntgrid = 20000;

Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]


CompilePrint@f1 == CompilePrint@f2
f1 = fcp1[Ct0, xRange, {0, dt*Ntgrid, dt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
f2 = fcp2[Ct0, xRange, {0, dt*Ntgrid, dt}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*True*)
(* {0.000642, Null} *)
(* {14.959721, Null} *)
```

So why does the C compilation so much slower than the WVM version, and how to speed it up?

**Update**

MarcoB gave a good suggestion to look at the compilation time independent of Mathematica. So I tested the compilation:

The documentation says the `CCompilerDriver` will be automatically involked when compiling to C. And it indeed seems quite slow.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]    
file = Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "fcp1.c"}], 
    f1]; // AbsoluteTiming
CreateObjectFile[{file}, "fcp1"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.505879, Null} *)
(* {7.194721, Null} *)
```

And the compiler  `CCompilerDriver` involked is Clang in my system

```
DefaultCCompiler[]
(* CCompilerDriver`ClangCompiler`ClangCompiler *)
```

so I also tested it outside MMA:

```
Import["!clang -v 2>&1", "Text"]
Import["!clang -shared -o " <> 
    ToString@FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "fcp1.so"}] <> " " <> 
        ToString@FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "fcp1.c"}] <> " -I" <>
         ToString[
         FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, 
       "SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/C/"}]] <> " 2>&1", 
   "Text"]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* "Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 Thread model: posix" *)

(* {0.750312, Null} *)


Import["!nm " <> ToString@FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "fcp1.so"}], "Text"]

".....
0000000000013140 T _fcp1
0000000000017030 b _funStructCompile
0000000000017020 d _initialize
                 U dyld_stub_binder"
```

It looks like compile outside of MMA is very fast.
So:

1. Why does `CCompilerDriver` take long time to compile?
2. CCompilerDriver takes about 7s in the last example, so why `Compile` take about 15s?

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question: you are asking about the time it takes to *compile* the function, not to *execute* it once it has been compiled, correct?

Comment: @MarcoB yes, that's correct.

Comment: Compilation to C requires a call to the external compiler/linker, and some disk writes. As far as I understand it, compilation to MVM happens in memory. Have you measured how long it takes your compiler to compile/link something to a DLL? That may end up being a significant part of the overhead you see in compilation to C

Comment: On my machine, **Windows 10** with Visual Studio 2015 C compiler, `f2` takes about 2 seconds. So maybe a different compiler will help you here.

Comment: I don't really know why compilation is so comparatively slow. I think I have missed something though: how is this typically going to affect performance? Of course, you would *not* compile your function *every time you evaluate it*. That approach does not seem to have any great upsides, but it is likely to kill any advantage you get from the compilation in all but the most extreme of cases.

Comment: With Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013 I am also getting 2 sec for `f2`. I guess its machine specific compiler issue.

Comment: For me, with MinGW GCC on Windows with *Mathematica* 9, it takes about 7.5 seconds the first time and 3.5 seconds the second time to compile `f2`. I think this is within the normal range. When you test Clang by itself, you are only compiling, not linking (I think; I've never used Clang). Linking may take considerable time and should certainly be included as well.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks. Do you know how can I test linking?

Comment: Use `-o` switch instead of `-c` in most compilers.

Comment: @OleksandrR. But what should I link to? I tried clang -o fcp1 fcp1.c and it says "_main" not defined.

Comment: Normally there is also a switch that indicates you are trying to build a library rather than an executable. In GCC, it's `-shared`. But you would be better off to read the Clang manual than to ask me, because I've never used it.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks. I updated. It seems that linking is also fast.

Comment: @MarcoB The function I'm working on take function arguments. So I have to recompile each time I evaluate with a different arguments.

Comment: Way too late, but I think the problem here is that you enforce the definition of the huge array `C0` to be inlined, although you only need its length. And I am not sure whether the _Mathematica_ and the _C_ compiler are able to optimize this out. I think the `MTensor` representing `C0` has first to be instantiated at runtime before its size can be queried. And instantiation needs to store all its values _in the program code_. So a lot of useless stuff to let the _C_ compiler chew on.