# Closing over array values makes Compile choke with CompilationTarget -> "C"

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, ccompilerdriver

When I attempt to `Compile` a closure which contains an array of the appropriate type, it works just fine with `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"`:

```
In[1]:= cf = With[{id = N@IdentityMatrix@500},
          Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}},
           id.v]]
Out[1]= CompiledFunction[<>]
```

However, when I try to compile to C, awful things happen.

```
In[2]:= With[{id = N@IdentityMatrix@500},
          Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}},
               id.v,
           CompilationTarget -> "C"]]
(* Kernel hangs and/or crashes here while trying to "render dynamic content" *)
```

Poking around in the directory that `Compile` compiles things in, I found a 6 MB source file that contained exactly 250 000 of lines of this (I gather it's supposed to be cleaned up, but that must not have happened when the kernel went kablooey):

```
#include "math.h"

#include "WolframLibrary.h"
[...]
static MTensor T0_1B = 0;

static MTensor* T0_1 = &T0_1B;

static mreal *P1;
[...]
P1 = MTensor_getRealDataMacro(*T0_1);
P1[0] = 1.;
P1[1] = 0.; 
P1[2] = 0.;
P1[3] = 0.;
P1[4] = 0.;
P1[5] = 0.;
P1[6] = 0.;
P1[7] = 0.;
P1[8] = 0.;
P1[9] = 0.;
[...]
P1[249998] = 0.;
P1[249999] = 1.;
```

The compilation appears to have succeeded, because there's also a 2.6 MB library object there, but then it tried to render something (maybe the fancy little `StandardForm` icon they have for `CompiledFunction`s now) and everything came to a screeching halt. Also, I suspect that may not be the best way to initialize that data for the tensor. Is there a way to make the compiler do something more useful here?

Comment: Somewhat related: 1. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91792/1871   (see the "Appendix: On injecting large expressions" part.) 2. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88899/1871

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
mv = Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}, {id, _Real, 2}},
   id.v,
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

v = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 500];

id = N[IdentityMatrix[500]];

res=mv[v, id]
```

It works without trouble.

Comment: +1, though for my particular use case it would be fairly painful, as the stuff that's going wrong is in generated, rather than handwritten, code.